# MUI linear determinate update progress state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a modal that does some async logic submitting to a database.

My `LinearDeterminate` component looks like this (using MUI):
[MUI Progress](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-progress/)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import LinearProgress from "@mui/material/LinearProgress";

export default function LinearDeterminate({ doneSoFar, allData }) {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prevProgress) => {
        if (prevProgress >= 100) {
          return 0;
        }
        return (doneSoFar / allData.length) * 100;
      });
    }, 500);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%", mt: 2 }}>
      <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={progress} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I'm using it in this modal:

```
import LinearDeterminate from "./LinearDeterminate";

export default function MyModal() {
  const data = []; // my data here
  let done = 0;

  const handleFunc = async () => {
    try {
      const promises = [];
      for (const row of data) {
        // some logic here
        done++; // incrementing done when every row is done
      }

      await Promise.all(promises);
    } catch (error) {}
  };
  return <LinearDeterminate doneSoFar={done} allData={data} />;
}
```

The problem is that the progress bar isn't moving at all. When console logging `done` it is incrementing correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```js
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
//..
useEffect(() => {
  const newProgress = (doneSoFar / allData.length) * 100;
  setProgress(newProgress);
}, [doneSoFar, allData]);
```

`useEffect` has `[doneSoFar, allData]` as dependency array. so whenever `doneSoFar` or `allData` changes, the effect will fire. inside `useEffect` the `progress` state is updated based on the new values of `doneSoFar` and `allData`.

Comment: Adding `[doneSoFar, allData])` in the dependency array solved the problem. I got rid of `setInterval` as well as it seems it is not needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SevenSouls yeah, you don't need the setInterval, you can track updates with useEffect and update your local state based on that

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you need to set done and data to state values in MyModal.

For example:

```
const [done, setDone] = useState(0);
const [data, setData] = useState(0);

setDone(prevDone => prevDone + 1);
setData(prevData => [...prevData, row]);
```

And you can try to debug doneSoFar value in LinearDeterminate component. For example:

```
console.log(doneSoFar);
```

And then, add `doneSoFar` and `allData` to useEffect hook dependencies in your LinearDeterminate component, for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setProgress((prevProgress) => {
    if (prevProgress >= 100) {
      return 0;
    }
    return (doneSoFar / allData.length) * 100;
  });
}, [doneSoFar, allData]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I set `done` as a state. When console logging `done` in `MyModal`, it is incrementing correctly; however, the bar is still not moving. Seems like there's something wrong in the `setInterval` logic.